# Matching 2nd camera to a scene

Tags: camera, fspy

I found nice looking house and wanted to recreate it, used fSpy instead of BLAM, but found it works well. I placed cubes instead of normal models. My problem is, that there is second and third photo of this room and i can't match perspective of the second camera to the ready scene. I tried fSpy, but it hasn't fitted it properly.
What should i do if i want to fit 2nd camera to both scene and reference by hand?
 [image][image][image]

Comment: Seems to me that it would work best to use motion tracking and manually place tracking points on points visible on all of the source images. Then solve the scene and let blender decide on camera placement and lens.

Comment: Ok but how can i do it with two still images?

Comment: I manually set these points, but the solve error is high (over 2). Generally, it correctly sets the camera to points, although the camera location has nothing to do with real models. Maybe it would be better to do these models completely from the beginning instead of rearranging the camera to fit the models?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. The nunmer of solve errors was about 3.2, but now it fits perfectly. Firstly i used fSpy, copied focal lenght and pasted it into camera settings in mation tracking. After that i changed refine from none to focal lenght and optical center. The most important thing is that i made a perpective point on the table. It caused so high solve error, but it works. Unfortunately i must redo models, but now it perfectly matches.